# Bluetooth broadcasting in android without BLE

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am working on a project to build an android application with bluetooth broadcasting capabilities. The latest bluetooth API (BLE) support broadcasting but I want to implement with old API where broadcasting is not supported by default. Is there any method I can do this ?

Comment: What do you use now? Be specific, share code.

Comment: The application is to broadcast a message for all available devices in the range. I am referring to this code https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-passion-release/samples/BluetoothChat/